# TestNG java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/primitives/Ints

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am new to learning TestNG. I followed these steps:

1. I have created testng class
2. @Test(dataProvider="registerData")
3. I wrote a method with four arguments and
4. @DataProvider
5. Call data provider

Then the error below pops up:

```
TestNG java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/primitives/Ints
```

I am using Eclipse Luna Release 2 (4.4.2), Window 7

Comment: please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) for the general cause of this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems below jar is not available in your classpath. 
com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar

Download from the link below and add it to your classpath.

[com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomgoogleguava160jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is known and already fixed (the fix will be available in the next version): https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1086

As workarround, you can downgrade your testng version or add Guava in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download com.google.guava_1.6.0.jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomgoogleguava160jar.htm)

   2. add .jar file to your project